# Generate HTML output with Python 2.x

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook

I need to generate HTML output with Python 2.*
If I used Python 3.*, I could write

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML("""
<script>
console.log("hello");
</script>
<b>HTML</b>
""")
```

But Python 2.* doesn`t support `IPython` module, so I can`t use `IPython.display import HTML`

I tried

```
output = "<html><body>test 1</body></html>"
print output
```

But the cell is generated with the following output:

```
"outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "<html><body>test 1</body></html>\n"
     ]
    }
   ]
```

I need the output to be of `text/html`

Comment: Where do you want to display this HTML?

Comment: @UrielEli no matter. console for example. It should be used for testing. Just a Jupyter-notebook cell which outputs an HTML

Comment: What console? IPython console is capable of displaying HTML, but it doesn't go for all other consoles.